# Why isn't my component's state computed property updating after Redux store updates its value?

Tags: react-native, redux

Why isn't my component's state computed property updating after Redux store updates its value?

I am using some helper methods to grab the sub-store via AppStore.getState().ApiStore for my isAuthenticated state property. It seems like when this store value updates, the component state value does not update. Does React Native not watch for store updates in computed component state properties?

My component looks like the below:

```
// Vendor
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native'
import AppStore from './Stores/AppStore'
import StoreHelpers from './Stores/StoreHelpers'

// Custom
import Login from './Components/Login/Login'
import Api from './Services/Api.js'

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  mainView: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#3b5998',
  },

});

// Main App Component
export default class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      isAuthenticated: !StoreHelpers.getApiStore().userBalanceResponse.error // Computed property from store
    }

    // Enable this for debugging

    console.log(this.state)

    AppStore.subscribe(() => {
     console.log(AppStore.getState())
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
        <Login />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
// AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => Main);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't see it because your component is not subscribed to the store. Anything to do with store is the job of redux and **NOT** React Native. So if you wrap your component inside react-redux connect and pass in mapStateToProps to it you should get the right computed value.

```js
// ... rest of imports
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Main App Component
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      isAuthenticated: this.props.isAuthenticated,
    }

    // ... rest of code

  }

  // ... rest of code
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  isAuthenticated: !userBalanceResponse: store.userBalanceResponse.error,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Main);
```

To make it work, make sure that you set up redux store properly. Wrap your root component within a Provider component and pass in store into it. Suppose your root component is called App, then it would look something like the following:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import Main from 'path-to-main/Main';

// we will pass this store to the Provider
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  // ... middlewares etc this is optional
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This was a very informative answer. Thank you for your help. I am still getting an error: Could not find 'store' in either the context or props of "Connect(Main)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to Connect(Main). I've tried the first suggested solution from the error, which did not help. I do not understand the second. Any ideas?

Comment: The first method should work. There's probably a mistake in your code. I've updated my answer to include an example on how to set up redux store on your component. Also the redux doc is a good source: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#passing-the-store